# How to change select option with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a table with the class "vuln-table" and the first column is full of checkboxes, while the last column are options

I've basically figured out how to do an alert box for only rows that contain a checked checkbox; however, I now need to figure out how to change the value of the selected option

Here's my js file:

```
function change_severity(severity) {
    $(".vuln-table tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find('td input:checked').each(function() {
            // this row has a checkbox selected
            // this row needs to have the select value changed
        });
    });
}
```

Here's the HTML that contains my options

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="sorting_1"><input type="checkbox" name="asfasdfd" id="vuln_checked_" value="asdfsdfa"></td>
<td>something</td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="test" id="kjhtkjehtehr"><option value="Severe">Severe</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Informational">Informational</option>
</select>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I'm passing in severity through a button click, and it always equals to one of those values. I just basically want to have the selected option to change to whatever "severity" is set to. So if I pass "Severe" to the function, then the selected option should now be "severe".

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes in HTML code.

Comment: They exist. I just didn't think it'd be necessary to paste it all here. Isn't there a way to use $(this) where I'm looking to put it? I'll update my example either way.

Comment: The `td` is unnecessary, since it has nothing to do with the question. The checkboxes however are a central part of the question.

Comment: Note that the advice is to post minimal reproducible code, not minimal code.

Comment: Expected behavior is not well defined. How is value determined?

Comment: Someone provided the assistance I needed, but I also updated my question for further clarification for anyone else. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/v1pje44v/12/

The below function fix the issue

```
function change_severity(severity) {
$(".vuln-table tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find('td input:checked').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().find("select").val(severity);
    });
});
}
```

Comment: This actually works perfectly for me since I can change the severity over and over without losing the previous value. Thanks so much to you and @Gothdo!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function change_severity(severity) {
    $(".vuln-table tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find('td input:checked').each(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('option[value="option value"]').remove();
            $(this).parent().parent().find("option:selected").val("option value").text("option value");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: @Gothdo  for wat purpose you have used these much selectors and made this more complicated?

Comment: @sundar For simplicity. I don't think it's more complicated.

Comment: @Gothd tats too much complicated.use this function change_severity(severity) {
    var tr; 
    $(".vuln-table tr").each(function() {
        tr = $(this);
        $(this).find('td input:checked').each(function() {
            tr.find('option[value="option value"]').remove();
            tr.find("option:selected").val("option value").text("option value");
        });
    });
}

Comment: @Gothdo are you around?remove your downvote.without knowing something you have downvoted.remove that

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_severity(severity) {
$(".vuln-table tr").find('td input:checked').each(function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find("select").val(severity);
});
```

}

change_severity("Informational")

Answer (score -1):

```
function change_severity(severity) {
    var tr;
    $(".vuln-table tr").each(function() {
        tr = $(this);
        $(this).find('td input:checked').each(function() {
            tr.find('td select').val('medium'); // add any option you want to change
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: @Gothd wat how come this will change all of select elements?

Comment: Sorry, I mistaken `select` with `option`. Anyway, AFAIK it's not possible to change value of a `select` element in this way.

Comment: @LewlSauce man always use less number of selectors.if you use more number of selectors that will affect your codes performance